# Use jq to transform JSON output to CSV complex structure

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have an existing json file that I need to transform, but am having trouble with it.

Here's an example of the structure:

```
jq -r '.document.results.summary.run.[] | [.run_number, .cinfo] ' input.json

[
  "42",
  [
    {
      "name": "Joe shmo",
      "state": "AZ",
      "city": "Phoenix"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane shmo",
      "state": "CA",
      "city": "Blythe"
  ]
]
[
  "84",
  [
    {
      "name": "Jake shmo",
      "state": "NY",
      "city": "Albany"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jay shmo",
      "state": "TN",
      "city": "Franklin"
  ]
]

I need to convert this to a CSV to look like: 
"run_number","cinfo.name","cinfo.state","cinfo.city"

Example: 
"42","Joe shmo","AZ","Phoenix"
"42","Jane shmo","CA","Blythe"
"84","Jake shmo","NY","Albany"
"84","Jay shmo","TN","Franklin"
```

I tried to use | @csv I get:

`jq: error (at input.json:1397): array ([{"@name":"...) is not valid in a csv row` 
I believe that this is because it is an array of multiple indexes. How can I transform the output using jq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried applying `@csv` to an array containing non-strings. You have to decompose them to get to the values.

```bash
jq -r '
  .document.results.summary.run.[] | . as {$run_number}
  | .cinfo[] | [$run_number, .name, .state, .city]
  | @csv
' input.json
```

If all goes well (I could have tested it if you had provided `input.json`), this should produce

```
"42","Joe shmo","AZ","Phoenix"
"42","Jane shmo","CA","Blythe"
"84","Jake shmo","NY","Albany"
"84","Jay shmo","TN","Franklin"
```

Comment: Here's a [jqplay.org demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RebSX1fQXHU) using example JSON input.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm, and I learned what I was stumbling on.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a valid JSON file in your code sample. Perhaps you meant to write this:

```
[
  [
    "42",
    [
      {
        "name": "Joe shmo",
        "state": "AZ",
        "city": "Phoenix"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane shmo",
        "state": "CA",
        "city": "Blythe"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    "84",
    [
      {
        "name": "Jake shmo",
        "state": "NY",
        "city": "Albany"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jay shmo",
        "state": "TN",
        "city": "Franklin"
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

In this case, you can use the command:

```
jq -r '.[] | .[0] as $run_number | .[1][] | [$run_number, .name, .state, .city] | @csv' input.json
```

and you will receive this result:

```
"42","Joe shmo","AZ","Phoenix"
"42","Jane shmo","CA","Blythe"
"84","Jake shmo","NY","Albany"
"84","Jay shmo","TN","Franklin"
```

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is showing a portion of the _**output**_ of his `jq` command.  I think the OP's `input.json` is more closely modeled by this [jqplay.org example](https://jqplay.org/s/RebSX1fQXHU).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to tag the following to the end of the `jq` filter you already have ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/668P7sqEF96)):

```
| [ .[0] ] + (.[1] [] | [ .[] ]) | @csv
```

The complete filter would be:

```
  .document.results.summary.run.[] 
| [.run_number, .cinfo] 
| [ .[0] ] + (.[1] [] | [ .[] ])
| @csv
```

To understand how it works, let's break it down to see what would happen to the first row produced by `[.run_number, .cinfo]`:

- The `.[1] []` would first unpack the info array so it would produce two objects, i.e.,

  ```
  {"name":"Joe shmo","state":"AZ","city":"Phoenix"}
  {"name":"Jane shmo","state":"CA","city":"Blythe"}
  ```
- These two objects are piped to `[ .[] ]` which would turn them into arrays as follows:

  ```
  ["Joe shmo","AZ","Phoenix"]
  ["Jane shmo","CA","Blythe"]
  ```
- Now, when you add that to `[ .[0] ]` (which would be `[ "42" ]`), `jq` would do an array concat to both arrays in the stream, resulting in:

  ```
  ["42","Joe shmo","AZ","Phoenix"]
  ["42","Jane shmo","CA","Blythe"]
  ```
- This gets passed into `@csv` filter producing the row we need.

The entire process repeats for the other `run` as well, and we have the desired output.